# DXF imports convert polylines to splines

Tags: bezier-curves, import

I am having this real headache issue.

I like to use Fusion360 to draw precise icons using the sketch tools they provide. But then animate them using blender. I am having issues getting the files to transfer over correctly because when I attempt to export the sketch as a DXF as a polyline blender seems to be converting and optimizing it to include splines with handles and such. I do not want this and its behavior is inconsistent.

[image: Two Imported Icons]

Here are two imported icons, they were both generated the same waybut the one on the right is correctly divided up. If I were to export the right one normally it would have a spline with handles instead of a dense polyline curve. But I don't know why the left one won't import in the same way.

Here is the DXF for the left icon https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F013yrU_jMiW-g6F-rIvQOrZxwYK0XUu/view?usp=sharing

The file contains no splines in its text. Same as the other one, is the blender addon treating them differently? Or am I missing something? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The DX file consists of lines, a circle, arcs, and a LWPOLYLINE object which is different than a polyline: https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dxfentities/lwpolyline.html The issue is not in the Blender importer, but how it was exported from Fusion360 . Please check their support for more information on how to convert the objects in your design to polylines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not in Blender's DXF importer.

The file has DXF objects like Circle, Arc, LWPOLYLINE and also Line. The curve objects are imported as Bezier type of curve and the Lines - as Poly.

If you don't want to deal with Fusion360 export settings - you can convert the imported in Blender object to **Mesh** first and convert it back to **Curve** (**3D View -> Object -> Convert**), which will automatically turn it to a Poly type of Curve.

The amount of segments to represent the curved parts can be controlled by setting the **Curve Resolution** in the **Curve Data** (which by default is 12)  *before converting to **Mesh***

Comment: Ohhh, I am not familiar with how DXF's are formatted. So I didn't know there were dedicated shapes for circles. I don't really know why I didn't assume this was the case since I do a lot of 3d printing and often deal with arcs and circles the same way. I guess I was a bit confused why one would behave how I wanted versus another thinking it was an LOD issue, but now I know its because I singled out one type of line as the problem.